# httpCallout @future

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, future, httprequest

can please someone tell me what I am doing wrong. I am only able to get 30 percent test converge. I am unable to get test converge for the http. Any suggestion is much appreciated  Thank you!

```java
public class TransferApplicantInvoc {
    public class inputRequest{
        @InvocableVariable(label='accountId')
        public Id accountId;
        @InvocableVariable(label='newTAOC')
        public String newTAOC;
        @InvocableVariable(label='newEast')
        public String newEast;
        @InvocableVariable(label='newCent')
        public String newCent;
        @InvocableVariable(label='newWest')
        public String newWest;
    }
            
    public class outputResponse{
        @InvocableVariable(label='errorMessage')
        public String errorMessage;
    }
                
    @InvocableMethod(label='executeApplicantTransfer')
    public static void testPost(List<TransferApplicantInvoc.inputRequest> inputList) {
        System.debug(inputList.get(0));
        makeCallout(inputList.get(0).accountId);
    }

    @future(callout=true)
    public static void makeCallout(Id accountId) {
        List<TransferApplicantInvoc.outputResponse> resList = new List<TransferApplicantInvoc.outputResponse>();
        TransferApplicantInvoc.outputResponse res = new TransferApplicantInvoc.outputResponse();

        try{
            List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
            Account acc = new Account();
            acc.id = String.escapeSingleQuotes(accountId);
            accList.add(acc);
            
            HttpRequest feedRequest = new HttpRequest();
            feedRequest.setEndpoint('xzy/');
            feedRequest.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
            
            JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
            gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeObjectField('accountList', accList);
            gen.writeEndObject();
            String jsonS = gen.getAsString();
            feedRequest.setBody(jsonS);
            feedRequest.setMethod('POST');
            feedRequest.setHeader('Content-Length', '45');
            feedRequest.setTimeout(20000);
            Http http = new Http();
            HTTPResponse feedResponse = http.send(feedRequest);
            String jsonStr = feedResponse.getBody();
            System.debug('Debug:' + jsonStr);
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.debug('Error: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

```java
@isTest
global class TransferApplicantInvocMock implements HttpCalloutMock {
    // Implement this interface method
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        // Optionally, only send a mock response for a specific endpoint
        // and method.
        System.assertEquals('xyz/', req.getEndpoint());
        System.assertEquals('Post', req.getMethod());
        
        // Create a fake response
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setBody( 'jsonStr');
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res;
    }
}
```

```java
@isTest
public class TransferapplicantInvocTest {
    @isTest    
    Public static void makeCalloutTest1(){     
        List<TransferApplicantInvoc.inputRequest> inputList = new List<TransferApplicantInvoc.inputRequest>();
        TransferApplicantInvoc.inputRequest input = new TransferApplicantInvoc.inputRequest();
        
        Test.startTest();
        TransferApplicantInvoc.makeCallout(input.accountId);
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new TransferApplicantInvocMock());
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are your test classes using the `global` access modifier?

Comment: They are `global` because that's what the Salesforce documentation [this is copied from uses](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm#:~:text=this%20interface%20method-,global%20HTTPResponse%20respond(HTTPRequest%20req)%20%7B,-//%20Optionally%2C%20only%20send)

Answer (score 3):

#### First issue: Bad exception practices

This pattern

```
try{
    // some code
}catch(Exception e){
    system.debug(e.getMessage());
}
```

is what I call *swallowing an exception*.

Swallowing exceptions is bad because when you do run into an issue it makes it harder to see what the actual issue is. It also causes your code to keep running, which can lead to strange gaps in coverage (and strange execution paths outside of testing). Being in an `@future` method makes things worse, because async contexts generate separate logs (and in my experience, Salesforce's auto-notification of failures is not great at handling async failures).

If you're going to catch exceptions, you should generally catch specific exceptions (`System.JSONException`, `System.DmlException`, etc...) rather than catch *all* exceptions. `catch(Exception e)` is affectionately called the "pokemon catch" (because you gotta catch 'em all) something you want to avoid.

If you're going to catch exceptions, you should do some explicit logging and/or notification so that the issue can be noticed by someone. Write into a log object, send an email, create a case in your bug tracking system. Do something, do anything, don't just leave it as an entry in a log that has a chance as being marked as successfully executed.

I'd recommend removing the try/catch altogether. If you run into an issue, you want to know about it (especially in unit tests).

#### Second issue: Using JSONGenerator

This is where I suspect the primary issue is. If you remove the try/catch and run your test again, I suspect that your test is running into an exception on `gen.writeObjectField('accountList', accList);`. If that's true, then you should notice that your coverage stops either at this line or on the line before it (even before you remove the try/catch).

I'm sure that there is *some* use for JSONGenerator, but it's something that you don't really want to be using unless you absolutely have to. It's extremely verbose, prone to errors in usage, and we have a much easier way to generate JSON strings through `JSON.serialize()`.

Using a small Apex class (and then serializing that) is one of the two common ways to generate JSON. In this case, that'd probably be overkill. The other common way to generate JSON is to make use of a List or a Map. If your top-level JSON entity is a list, you'd use a list. If it's an object, you'd use a Map.

```
// Be careful with naming
// If you use 'json' as the variable name, you'll shadow the JSON class making its
//   static methods unable to be used.
String myJson = JSON.serialize(new Map<String, Object>{
    'accountList' => accList
    // You can create complex object structures by continuing to add nested
    //   Map<String, Object> or Lists, though you don't need to go that deep
    //   given your example code
});
```

#### Third issue: not preparing test data

Tests, by default, do not have access to any data in your org (with the exception of "setup objects" like Users). This is a good thing, as it prevents changes made in tests from being persisted in actual, live data, and it forces us to make our own test data (which helps ensure that the tests can pass in your sandbox as well as in production).

Your `input` variable isn't going to have any data in it unless you add data in a constructor (which you don't have) or add it yourself.

You'll need to (at the very least) create a test account in your test method. Better practice would be to define a method with the `@testSetup` annotation to handle creating test data, but let's take things one step at a time.

If your test is only stressing how the `makeCallout()` method behaves, then you don't need to go through the trouble of setting up a `List<TransferApplicantInvoc.inputRequest>`.

The minimal test method you'd use for testing the `makeCallout()` directly would be something like

```java
    @isTest    
    Public static void makeCalloutTest1(){     
        Account testAccount = new Account(Name = 'my test account');
        insert testAccount;
        
        Test.startTest();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new TransferApplicantInvocMock());
        TransferApplicantInvoc.makeCallout(testAccount.accountId);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
```

#### Fourth issue: not setting the calloutmock before calling your code

I fixed this in my example above, but if I hadn't, you'd run into a "cannot make a callout from a test" error because of this (after applying the previous fixes mentioned).

You've created a mock callout class, and are using it in your test, but only after you're calling `makeCallout()`.

The mock needs to be set before the callout it's meant to mock is called.

Instead of

```
Test.startTest();
        TransferApplicantInvoc.makeCallout(input.accountId);
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new TransferApplicantInvocMock());
        Test.stopTest();
```

The mock should be set first

```
Test.startTest();
// set the mock first
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new TransferApplicantInvocMock());

// then you can call the code that contains a callout
TransferApplicantInvoc.makeCallout(input.accountId);
Test.stopTest();
```

#### General testing advice

- You usually want to stick to testing a single method at a time, and write at least one test for every public/global method
- Try to keep each test as small as possible and test only a single path through the code (i.e. if you have an if/else if/else, you'd want to strongly consider writing one test for each possible branch and avoid just covering all branches in a single test)
- Make sure to make assertions! Assertions are the main way you'll know if something is wrong. Figure out what changes when you call your code, and assert that the change has happened. An example here would be to check that `Limits.getCallouts()` increments by 1 (comparing the value before calling `makeCallout()` to the value after calling that method)

Comment: Ok, so from brief testing the issue is actually with `acc.id = String.escapeSingleQuotes(accountId);` (accountId is null, can't pass null into escapeSingleQuotes) rather than with the JSON generator, but that doesn't make any changes to my overall recommendations.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion! This is not my code. I am not a programmer. I was giving this code by someone else. I am doing my best to get the 75 percent coverage.

Comment: @Alex you say you are not a programmer, but you are doing development so you are welcome to wear this title proudly. That said, the person who gave you this code should have also given you a proper test which worked, asserted the business requirements and had adequate code coverage. This is a failure on their part.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting mock after actually doing callout, swap these 2 lines of code and it should work for you.

```
TransferApplicantInvoc.makeCallout(input.accountId);
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new TransferApplicantInvocMock());
```

Comment: Thanks Marjia, unfortunately I still get the same coverage after the swiped.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are not testing the invocable method `testPost`. Instead, you are going straight to testing the future method. You are going to need a mocked accountId

```
// given a mock account
Account mockAccount = new Account(Name = 'foo');
insert mockAccount;

// given a mock invocable request
TransferApplicantInvoc.inputRequest inputRequest = new TransferApplicantInvoc.inputRequest();
request.Id = mockAccount.Id;
request.xxx = // the other fields

List<TransferApplicantInvoc.inputRequest> inputList = new 
      List<TransferApplicantInvoc.inputRequest>{inputRequest)};


    
Test.startTest();
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new TransferApplicantInvocMock());
// when invocable called
List<TransferApplicantInvoc.outputResponse> results = TransferApplicantInvoc.testPost(inputList);
Test.stopTest();
// then verify work
// asserts go here
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the suggestions. I love the Salesforce community. With all of your suggestions, I was able to achieve the 88 coverage. Here is my test.

```
@isTest
public class TransferApplicantInvocTest {
   @isTest
    public static void makeCalloutTest(){
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new TransferApplicantInvocMock());
        TransferApplicantInvoc.inputRequest input = new TransferApplicantInvoc.inputRequest();
           account acc = new account (Name = 'fake test');
        insert acc;
        input.accountId = acc.Id;
        Test.startTest();
        TransferApplicantInvoc.makeCallout(input.accountId);
         Test.stopTest();   
        system.assert(true, 'success');
    
        
    }
}
```